# Apis de twitter

Tags: vue.js

**Buenos dias **
Como me conecto  a la Api de twtter

ya cree el usuario en twitter developer
cree la aplicacion en twitter .
ya tengo mi  (API key)..
 ahora necesito conectarlo con mi backend en  vuejs.. 
alguna idea ?
intente conectar vuejs + auth0 haciendo esto

auth0.com/docs/connections/social/twitter mis resultados fueron

{ "error": "access_denied", "error_description": "Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'" }..

solo quiero aplicar la api de twtter a una aplicacion  vuejs ya hecha ..

Comment: Debes colocar (código) lo que llevas hasta el momento, de igual forma los errores que te salen.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado así como los fallos obtenidos

Comment: intente conectar  vuejs + auth0 haciendo esto 
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/twitter
 mis resultados fueron {
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'"
}

Comment: Toda la información de lo que has hecho, más el código escrito y los errores van en tu pregunta edita y agrega

Comment: listo. ya lo he editado

Comment: hay algo muy confuso en ese error. .. si tu app es de escritorio, porque decis que usas vue??? y si es de escritorio, el error dice que estas usando el callback equivocado. Para el caso, como haces la llamada?